# Self-intersecting problem in Canadian census tracts shapefile?

Tags: r, error, interpolation, self-intersection

I need to pass some data stored at the census tract level in Toronto to dissemination areas. When I run the Areal Weighted Interpolation package (code below), I get an invalid topology error (see below the code). Has anyone encounter this issue with the Canadian census boundary files? Any ideas how to fix it?

Code:

```
Toronto_DA_pop <- aw_interpolate(Toronto_DA, tid = DAUID, source = Toronto_CT_pop, sid = CTUID, weight = "sum", output = "tibble", extensive = c("population, population_50"))
```

Error:

> Evaluation error: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 4012552.0600000001 1988270.4571450001 at 4012552.0600000001 1988270.4571450001.

Comment: Are you using the Cartographic Boundary File or the  Digital Boundary File? https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2016-eng.cfm

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all

I did fixed it with QGIS, but a more streamlined solution was to simply write in R:

```
Toronto_DA_fixed = st_make_valid(Toronto_DA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the *Fix Geometries* processing tool in QGIS. Before running it - verify the geometry errors with menu *Vector>Geometry Tools>Check Validity*.  Then if it picks up errors run the *Fix Geometries*.